# HTTP Request to Steam Gives 401 Response

Tags: python, http, request

I've been trying to use the developer tools on my browser to find ways of getting information, so I am attempting to get a large list of Steam user's names via an HTTP request for fun.

The problem was that I can't use the network tab of the 'Inspect Element' feature to track my search query because it is sent via JavaScript when the enter key is pressed. Fair enough... I look through the js file and find the GET request. It requires a session ID, so I open the console and get my session ID.

Here is where I am stuck: This is the GET request from the js file

```js
url: 'https://steamcommunity.com/search/SearchCommunityAjax',
type: 'GET',
data: {
 text: search_text,
 filter: search_filter,
 sessionid: g_sessionID,
 steamid_user: g_steamID,
 page: this.m_nPage
}
```

I have tried passing all the arguments as if I were actually using the browser, via python (the session ID is blocked in case it is sensitive?):

```
data = {'sessionid': '********', 'text': 'test', 'filter': 'users', 'steamid_user': 'false', 'page': 1}
requests.get('https://steamcommunity.com/search/SearchCommunityAjax', data=data)
```

And the requests yields a 401 response, I am not authorized. I tried another request with JUST the session ID, in case there was a formatting error with the other parameters, but to no avail.

I should note that I am able to do this via the web interface without logging in. The only form of authentication for this request seems to be the session ID.

Like I said, I really have no need for this to work, but I felt it would be nice to know why it isn't working, so I can improve my skills! Thanks for your help.

Comment: 401 response probably means that url requires a username and password, which you don't appear to be sending.

Comment: I am able to search for users on the website without logging in.

Comment: Perhaps there's a cookie value the site is looking for that you aren't sending, or maybe it's rejecting you based on some header value (sites often reject requests if the `User-Agent` header looks like a robot.)

Comment: @JohnGordon is correct - I can make the query successfully in the browser by typing it in the search bar. When I use requests to spoof the header to that of firefox, it is successful!